# Generating similar random points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, proximity, nearest-neighbor

I have [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nwhJV8sBpv9REVEO9jAnHckvi2jaxjjN/view?usp=sharing) (Lat, Lon) of 32 buildings, and their plot in QGIS is given below in red dots. Now based on the calculated mean distance (Nearest neighbor analysis) between these points, I want to generate similar kind of random points for the same area.

**What I tried:**
I already tried QGIS plugin "Random points" but it seems it only accepts the distance in degrees, not in meters.

[image]

Comment: The "Random points ..." algorithms do use the crs units of the input layer. If you want to run it using meters, project your input layer to a metric system before.

Comment: Are you trying to anonymize the points? If so, you need to be very careful about the process. There's dedicated anonymization plugins available for qgis which utilise algorithms specifically designed for this purpose.

Comment: @ndawson. Exactly. I am trying to anonymize the data to preserve privacy and attempting to generate the similar kind of data which mimics the characteristics of original data. At the end, the geographical distribution should be similar in the map.

Comment: @MrXsquared. Which metric system should be used for using meters?. I am currently using WGS 84 EPSG:4326 coordinate system.